# FileLogTraceListener throwing System.IO.Exceptions

Tags: .net, windows

I am trying to work out why one of our legacy applications keeps throwing exceptions on a daily basis.  It's a VB.Net Windows service and it uses the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener` class to do the logging.

However, it throws the following exception and I can't work out what would be causing it:

```
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.get_Length()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.ReferencedStream.get_FileSize()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.ResourcesAvailable(Int64 newEntrySize)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.WriteLine(String message)
```

It seems to be thrown once a day at the moment and the issue is that I need to make sure that everything is logged.  In this case it's not acceptable for me to just catch and swallow the exception and the log to be omitted.

I have tried to look into possible causes for this Windows error message (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE - 0x06) but I can't seem to find anything specific.

Comment: Do you have any config settings for FileLogTracerListener?

Comment: I should point out that this works fine in my dev, test and QA environments and only causes the windows error (periodically) in my live environment. I don't think that the config would be the issue in this case. I am beginning to suspect that it may be much lower level than the .net framework (i.e. the windows cluster or some clone process on the server hard disk).

Comment: Is there any other detail that you can provide so someone and reproduce this and possibly help you?

Comment: Does more than one process (or even AppDomain) write to the same file?

Answer (score 0):

To aid problem diagnosis check the following:

- [Disable Trace UseGlobalLock For Better Tracing Performance](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2009/01/08/Disable-Trace-UseGlobalLock-For-Better-Tracing-Performance.aspx)

  <configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
      <trace **useGlobalLock="false"** />
      <sources>
        <source name="MySource" switchValue="All">
          <listeners> ...
- Rule out logging from multi- Threaded/AppDomain/Services.
- Using [Perfmon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) check if an intensive IO operation is happening at the same time, eg disk is getting backed up...
- Make sure drivers are up-to-date.
- If the above fails and you want to find out the root cause you need to use adplus to take a memory dump and use [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) with SOS to see the root cause.

If all that fails to narrow down the problem [replace the Servers disk drives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzGWvZAd228).